# SSR and client requests with separate frontend and backend servers (Next and Nest)

Tags: authentication, next.js, nestjs

I've got a NestJS backend holding the data (including the users) and a NextJS frontend. In my current setup, Next redirects all requests to an /api route to Nest and Nest handles basically anything associated with authentication and serving the data. The authentication is done by Nest placing an httpOnly cookie with a sessionToken

I am trying to implement SSR, therefore Next needs to be able to access userdata. I was thinking about either:

- giving Next access to the database
- requests to Next include the sessionCookie -> Next could fetch the backend adding this cookie as a header

Another solution could be to handle user authentication in Next and giving Next an accessToken for the backend (so Next requests the data with it's personal token and not the sessionToken of the user). I tried to avoid this as I am more comfortable with Nest than Next/NextAuth and I would like to use stateful sessions (I don't like webtokens) and username/password authentication. Also, the frontend and backend would each need to have a users table (frontend for authentication, backend for storing the userdata). Also, there would still be some get requests from the client to receive userdata, so those requests would also need to be passed through the frontend (or the frontend needs to provide some way for the client to access the nest backend).

Is there a recommended approach to handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tying hard, but I'm having the same issue, I'm getting the "Set-Cookie" from my server backend API, but it stick with the nextjs front part (browser) as I'm using "use client"

May be by using this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions#convention
We can handle the "Set-Cookie" from the server-side and share it with the front if need be.

I need to try